# Calling ApplicationInfo.loadLabel too many times leads to crash

Tags: android, android-package-managers, egl, android-applicationinfo

I have a severe issue about getting the appName from all apps in the device - both systemapps and userapps. The problem arises if there's is too many - in my Samsung S7 userapps and systemapps sums up to 433.

There seems to be a limit how many calls that can be made to ApplicationInfo's method "loadLabel". For instance - if I only fetch name from systemapps it works fine - same if I instead only fetch names from userapps. But if I fetch both userapps and systemapps the App crashces - especially if I have a progressbar showing loading.

It's an exception outside the JVM (EGL seems to be angry) but before the fatal signal one can see messages about too many files open and could not get resourceID for. etc.

My question is - is there a simple way to make this works?

I use asynctask and here's a snippet of **doInBackground**

```
@Override
public String doInBackground(String ... params) {

    //commenting out one the calls makes everything work
    //if you call both the app crashces
    appInfoRetriever.parseUserApps();
    appInfoRetriever.parseSystemApps(); 

    return "done! :)";
}
```

And here is the appInfoRetriever

```
  public AppInfoRetriever_(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    packageInfoList = getInstalledPackages(context, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    split();

}

private void split() {

    for(PackageInfo pInfo: packageInfoList) {

       if(isSystemApp(pInfo.packageName))
           packageInfoListS.add(pInfo);
       else
           packageInfoListU.add(pInfo);

    }


}

public void parseUserApps() {

    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    for (PackageInfo pInfo: packageInfoListU) {

        ApplicationInfo info = pInfo.applicationInfo;
        parseHelper(info);
        AppDataHolder appDataHolder = parseHelper(info);
        appUserDataHolderList.add(appDataHolder);

    }

}

public void parseSystemApps() {

    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    for (PackageInfo pInfo: packageInfoListS) {

        ApplicationInfo info = pInfo.applicationInfo;
        AppDataHolder appDataHolder = parseHelper(info);
        appSystemDataHolderList.add(appDataHolder);

    }

}

private AppDataHolder parseHelper(ApplicationInfo info) {


    //namn
    String appName = "";
    try {
        appName = info.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("UNDANTAG loadLabel(PackageManager)");
        e.printStackTrace();
        appName = "null";
    }

    AppDataHolder appDataHolder = new AppDataHolder();
    appDataHolder.setAppName(appName);
    //appDataHolderList.add(appDataHolder);
    return appDataHolder;
}
```

And here is the critical row that is intolerant against to many calls

```
 appName = info.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
```

**The exceptions in logcat**

```
 03-24 18:03:19.337 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 18, previously 25
ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 316, previously 454
ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 18, previously 25
ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 316, previously 454
 03-24 18:03:19.346 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 576, previously 575
ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 169, previously 777
 03-24 18:03:19.578 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 1313, previously 1357
 03-24 18:03:22.029 2288-2306/se.task.asynctrial E/Parcel: fcntl(F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC) failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 1, error: Too many open files
 03-24 18:03:22.029 2288-2306/se.task.asynctrial I/OpenGLRenderer: Surface query width is 1440
 03-24 18:03:22.030 2288-2306/se.task.asynctrial A/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set damage region on surface 0x769e8ec780, error=EGL_BAD_ACCESS
 03-24 18:03:22.059 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/system/priv-app/FingerprintService2/FingerprintService2.apk': Too many open files
 03-24 18:03:22.060 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/zipro: Error opening archive /system/priv-app/FingerprintService2/FingerprintService2.apk: I/O Error
 03-24 18:03:22.060 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial D/asset: failed to open Zip archive '/system/priv-app/FingerprintService2/FingerprintService2.apk'
 03-24 18:03:22.067 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f070004
 03-24 18:03:22.068 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f070004 in package com.samsung.android.fingerprint.service
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070004
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:353)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2165)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:173)
    at se.task.asynctrial.AppInfoRetriever_.parseHelper(AppInfoRetriever_.java:88)
    at se.task.asynctrial.AppInfoRetriever_.parseSystemApps(AppInfoRetriever_.java:75)
    at se.task.asynctrial.AsyncLoader.doInBackground(AsyncLoader.java:34)
    at se.task.asynctrial.AsyncLoader.doInBackground(AsyncLoader.java:8)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 03-24 18:03:22.071 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/system/priv-app/SamsungCamera7/SamsungCamera7.apk': Too many open files
 03-24 18:03:22.071 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/zipro: Error opening archive /system/priv-app/SamsungCamera7/SamsungCamera7.apk: I/O Error
 03-24 18:03:22.071 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial D/asset: failed to open Zip archive '/system/priv-app/SamsungCamera7/SamsungCamera7.apk'
 03-24 18:03:22.078 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f09012c
 03-24 18:03:22.078 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f09012c in package com.sec.android.app.camera
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f09012c
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:353)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2165)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:173)
    at se.task.asynctrial.AppInfoRetriever_.parseHelper(AppInfoRetriever_.java:88)
    at se.task.asynctrial.AppInfoRetriever_.parseSystemApps(AppInfoRetriever_.java:75)
    at se.task.asynctrial.AsyncLoader.doInBackground(AsyncLoader.java:34)
    at se.task.asynctrial.AsyncLoader.doInBackground(AsyncLoader.java:8)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 03-24 18:03:22.080 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/system/app/Bluetooth/Bluetooth.apk': Too many open files
 03-24 18:03:22.080 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial W/zipro: Error opening archive /system/app/Bluetooth/Bluetooth.apk: I/O Error
 03-24 18:03:22.080 2288-2307/se.task.asynctrial D/asset: failed to open Zip archive '/system/app/Bluetooth/Bluetooth.apk'
```